# Irreducible Markov chain and invariant measure

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

We consider a Markov chain $\left(X,P\right)$
  on a finite state space $X$. 
We denote $P:=\left(p_{x,y}\right)_{x,y\in X}$
  and for $n\in\mathbb{N}$
  $P^{n}:=\left(p_{x,y}^{(n)}\right)_{x,y\in X}$.

Assume that $\left(X,P\right)$   is irreducible. Let $\pi$
  be the unique $P$-invariant measure on $X$. Prove that there exists $\rho\in]0,1[$  and $c>0$
  such that

$$\forall x,y\in X,\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\left|P^{n}(x,y)-\pi(y)\right|\leq c\rho^{n}$$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This should be immediate from Perron-Frobenius (maybe with a little extra finesse to account for the nondiagonalizable case). Where are you having trouble?

Comment: Can you more precise?

Comment: By Perron-Frobenius, the largest eigenvalue is $1$ and it has only one eigenvector, namely the invariant measure. So in the diagonalizable case your result follows pretty much immediately ($\rho$ is the next largest eigenvalue). In the nondiagonalizable case it still works out but you need a bit more work to proceed this way.

Comment: Could you give me more details? How does this result follow immediately even in the case diagonalizable?

Comment: Perron-Frobenius tells you that the eigenvalue of 1 is simple (i.e. it has a 1D eigenspace). So given a distribution $p$ and assuming the transition matrix $P$ is diagonalizable, $p P^n = \pi + \sum_{i=2}^N c_i \lambda_i^n q_i$, where $N$ is the number of elements of $X$, $c_i$ are coefficients depending on $p$, $\lambda_i$ are the other eigenvalues, and $q_i$ are the other eigenvectors. Now replace all of the $\lambda_i$ with the second largest eigenvalue and recover your estimate.

Comment: What is $p$? Is it $\pi$?

Comment: $p$ is some distribution, written as a row vector and typically different from $\pi$.

Comment: For the convergence, you also need aperiodicity.  For example, the Markov chain with transition matrix $\left(\begin{matrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{matrix}\right)$ is irreducible with unique stationary distribution $\left(\begin{matrix}1/2 & 1/2\end{matrix}\right)$, but the convergence does not hold.

Comment: You should post your own answer @Ian

Answer (score 1):

If you have an irreducible, aperiodic Markov chain on a finite state space, you can apply the Perron-Frobenius theorem to conclude that the eigenvalue of (strictly) largest magnitude is $1$ and its eigenspace is $1$-dimensional. Up to normalization this eigenspace is given by the (unique) invariant distribution $\pi$. (As an aside, Perron-Frobenius still gives you that the eigenvalue of largest magnitude is $1$ if the chain is not aperiodic, but in this case it may be only nonstrict, as $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ demonstrates. In this case the convergence may fail.)

Denote the transition matrix by $P$ (in the row-stochastic convention). So if the initial distribution is $p$, then the distribution at time $n$ is $p P^n$. If $P$ is diagonalizable, then the diagonalized form of this expression reads:

$$p P^n = \sum_{i=1}^N c_i \lambda_i^n q_i = \pi + \sum_{i=2}^N c_i \lambda_i^n q_i.$$

where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues, $q_i$ are the (left) eigenvectors, and $c_i$ are coefficients depending on $p$. Take the eigenvectors to be sorted by magnitude and the eigenvectors to be unit (in whatever norm we're using). By the triangle inequality:

$$|p P^n - \pi| \leq \sum_{i=2}^N |\lambda_i|^n |c_i|$$

Replace $|\lambda_i|$ by the second largest eigenvalue in magnitude, which is $|\lambda_2|$ in this setup:

$$|p P^n - \pi| \leq |\lambda_2|^n \sum_{i=2}^N |c_i|.$$

Your result follows. In the nondiagonalizable case you can make a similar proof, but writing it out is significantly more cumbersome, because the Jordan normal form introduces some additional factors.

Comment: What is my $c$ and $\rho$ in your estimate?

Comment: @chuyenvien94 $\rho=|\lambda_2|$ and $c=\sum_{i=1}^n |c_i|$. You might need to do a little work to ensure that this has a bound independent of $p$ (I think this is just a continuity argument, though).

Comment: @chuyenvien94 Yes: in this case $c$ is the $1$-operator norm of the inverse eigenvector matrix. In the non-diagonalizable case it is the $1$-operator norm of the inverse generalized eigenvector matrix, possibly with a factor of $N^k$ if the second largest eigenvalue is a defective eigenvalue.